# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in, como resolver?

Tags: php, mysqli

Quero inserir os valores do formulario no banco de dados, porém apresenta o erro.

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Código linkar php:

```
<?php
    include_once('_php/conn.php');
    if (isset($_POST['addProdutoVenda'])){
        addProdutoVenda();
    }
?>

Código do formulário:
<form class="formVenda"  method="post">
    <h3>NOVA VENDA</h3>
    <label>Codigo: </label>
    <input required="yes" type="search" name="codigo" list="listaCodigoProduto" placeholder="00000"><br><br>

    <label>Descrição: </label>
    <input required="yes" type="search" name="descricao" list="listaNomeProduto" placeholder="Camisa Rosa V"><br><br>

    <label>QTD: </label>
    <input required="yes" type="number" name="quantidade" placeholder="6">

    <input type="submit" name="addProdutoVenda" name="">
</form>
```

Arquivo PHP conexão e inserção:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','nik') or die(mysqli_error());

function addProdutoVenda(){

$cod = $_POST['codigo'];
$desc = $_POST['descricao'];
$qtd = $_POST['quantidade'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO produtos VALUES";
$sql.= "('$cod', '$desc','$qtd')";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

}

?>
```

Comment: A variável `$con` não existe no contexto da sua função, logo ela é nula.

Answer (score 2):

Não possível (nem desejavel) acessar variáveis globais dentro de um função. A funçao `addProdutoVenda()` não enxerga a variável `$con`, por isso o erro ( conexão inválida).

Para solucionar isso, passe a conexão como argumento da função:

mude a assinatura para:

```
function addProdutoVenda($con){
```

E a chamada deve ser assim:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','nik') or die(mysqli_connect_error());
addProdutoVenda($con);
```

A ideia de criar funções é ter blocos de códigos que possam ser reaproveitados em várias situações, ao utilizar elementos externos (`$_POST`) dentro sua função fica dependente de um form enviado por post, a sugestão para eleminar essa problema é a mesma, passar o `$_POST` como argumento.

A função não retorna nenhuma valor nem trata o erro, logo não é possível saber se a operação foi realizada com sucesso ou não.

Comment: Ou, dentro do escopo da função adicionar `global $con;`.